# Media Queries CSS trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

I have 2 divs, with IDs `re1` and `re2`, both of their widths are set to 100% as their max-widths (800px and 400px) mean that both divs will stay on the same line in my container which has a max width of 1200px. This also means that on a mobile phone when the two divs become stacked each div will fill the width of the screen. The problem arises on mid sized screens ie. ipad, the size of the screen means that both of the divs go on a separate line, but due to their max-widths they have different sized widths which looks awful. So I tried to change their widths using media queries so they would stay on the same line for ipad but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
#re1 { width: 66.67%; }
#re2 { width: 33.33%; }
}
```

I have tried using the above values as default without the media queries and it has the desired effect, so it is something to do with the query itself. How do I get the divs' widths to change to 66/33% only when viewed on screens of the above resolutions?

Comment: If you are targeting iPad 3 or 4, than you should use `webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`.

Comment: Try t oset width to your divs 66.6% and 33.3% Which is the same width of 800 and 400 when container has 1200.

Comment: @AlexPrinceton tried that, no luck.

Comment: @Barnee I've tried 1/2 and completely removing the webkit like, none of it is working for me.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3etkk1 re1 and re2 are misplace in the html.. re2 is outside the 1200px container..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
#re1 { width: 66.67%; }
#re2 { width: 33.33%; }

}
```

Comment: a question: why are you targeting the pixel ratio too? 1 is default anyway.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the media query code from a website displaying the correct resolutions for ipads. Either way, even when I don't target it it doesn't do anything.

Comment: can you post a js fiddle or something? like your whole css file maybe?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3etkk1 put both re1 and re2 in the same container and try again my code

Comment: ahhh, I misplaced a `</div>` I've fixed this now so they are in the same container but still no luck.

Comment: the problem is in your css i believe, not the mediaqueries. i see tables and that's anti-responsive, also give your container overflow:auto, eliminate the redundant width:100% to the divs with max-width, be sure your slider plugin is responsive (else none of this makes sense) and carefully review your code because i see a lot of confusion in there. the problem is too complex to be solved here but i'm pretty sure the mediaqueries are not your main problem